# Javascript: dynamic drop down box update

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu

I have a dynamic drop down box when I select a hotel it brings out the respective dates. Now I want to add the times in a separate drop down.I tried adding a another parameter in the function but to no success. For example if I pic CIA it will show the date 10/09/13 and 11/09/13 in the drop down date. Now i would like to add in time selections 19:00 and 18:00 in its own drop down.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function populate(s1,s2){
var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
s2.innerHTML = "";
if(s1.value == "CIA to Table Bay Hotel" || s1.value == "CIA to The Portswood Hotel" || s1.value == "CIA to The Commodore Hotel" || s1.value == "CIA to Victoria and Alfred Hotel" ){
var optionArray = ["-1|Pick a date","10/09/13|10/09/13","11/09/13|11/09/13"];
} else if(s1.value == "Table Bay Hotel to CIA" || s1.value == "The Portswood Hotel to CIA" || s1.value == "The Commodore Hotel to CIA" || s1.value == "Victoria and Alfred Hotel to CIA" ){
var optionArray = ["-1|Pick a date","14/09/13|14/09/13","15/09/13|15/09/13"];
}
for(var option in optionArray){
var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
var newOption = document.createElement("option");
newOption.value = pair[0];
newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
s2.options.add(newOption);
}
}
</script>

<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><span class="style1"><span class="style7">*</span>Transfer?</span></td>
<td><select id="where" name="where" onChange="populate(this.id,'date')">
<option value="Pick up point">Pick up point</option>
<option value="CIA to Table">CIA to Table Bay Hotel</option>
<option value="CIA to Portswood ">CIA to The Portswood Hotel</option>
<option value="CIA to Commodore">CIA to The Commodore Hotel</option>
<option value="CIA to Victoria and Alfred Hotel">CIA to Victoria and Alfred Hotel</option>
<option value="Table to CIA">Table Bay Hotel to CIA</option>
<option value="Portswood to CIA">The Portswood Hotel to CIA</option>
<option value="Commodore to CIA">The Commodore Hotel to CIA</option>
<option value="Victoria and Alfred Hotel to CIA">Victoria and Alfred Hotel to CIA</option>
</select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><span class="style4"><span class="style7">*</span>Which Date? </span></td>
<td><select id="date" name="date"></select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><span class="style4"><span class="style7">*</span>Time? </span></td>
<td><select id="time" name="time"></select></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. that javascript code is poorly written.

But to answer your question and hack around it.

```
onChange="propulate(this.id, 'date', 'time')"

function populate(s1, s2, s3) {
  ...
  var s3 = document.getElementById(s3);
  s3.innerHTML = '';
  ...
  if (s1.value == ...) {
     timeOptionArray = ["-1|Pick a time", "19:00|19:00", "18:00|18:00"];
  }
  ...
  for (var option in timeOptionArray) { ... }
```

This would be additions to your code, not replacements.

A couple suggestions:

- Give a better name to s1, s2, something like `transferSelectId` and `dateSelectId`
- Dont declare variables with the same name as the arguments inside the `populate` function, so name them `transferSelect` and `dateSelect`.
- Declare the `optionArray` variable outside the `if` conditions and only do it once
- Now that you have date and time, which get populated in the same way, extract a method to populate them (e.g.) `function populateSelect(node, options) { ... }` which sets the innerHTML to empty and creates the options.