# Dynamic drop down list NON-DATABASE php

Tags: php

I'm trying to create a changing drop down list in php, but without a database.  Here's what I came up with so far

```
<body>

<form method = "post">
 <table>

 <tr>
     <td>
     <p>Name</p>
     </td>
     <td><input type="text" name="Name" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
        <td><p>State</p>
        </td>
        <td>
            <select name = "State">
            <option value = "PA"> Pennsylvania</option>
            <option value = "CA"> California</option>
            <option value = "AZ"> Arizona</option>
            <option value = "NY"> New York</option>
            <option value = "FL"> Florida</option>
        </select>
        </td>
</tr>

    <td><input type="submit" name = "formSubmit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
        if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']))
        {
            if(empty($_POST['Name']))
            {
                echo("You forgot your name");
            }

            else
            {

            }
        }
?>

</body>
```

I had planned to use the 'else' statement to generate my second drop down list, but so far nothing I've tried has worked.  I've looked all over for ideas, but most of the information I've come across has dealt with databases.  This isn't a database, it's a single PHP program.  Maybe I have the wrong idea of how this works.  Should I try calling a function that creates the form ahead of time or am I completely off base for what I'm attempting?

Comment: What is your end goal? If you have write privileges there's no reason why you can't write whatever you want to a flat text file and generate your dropdown from that.

Comment: do you want it to be dynamic, i.e. no page loads?

Comment: Kai: Sorry, the idea is when the user picks a state, another drop down list is generated or displayed that shows cities pertaining to that state, then when they select the city, it will report their selections.    


Snow: That would be ideal, however at this point if there's a simpler alternative I'll work towards that.

Answer (score 0):

To do so you need javascript
  There is already a question posted related to yours

[javascript-dynamic-drop-down-box-update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578294/javascript-dynamic-drop-down-box-update)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery would give you a true dynamic result without having to reload the page. However if you want to use PHP to add what is in the textbox to the list of values then you can use PHP session as an array to hold the values like this.

```
<?php
session_start();
    if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']))
    {
        if(empty($_POST['Name']))
        {
            echo("You forgot your name");
        }

        else
        {
            $name = $_POST['Name'];
            if(isset($_SESSION['List']))
            {
                $index = count($_SESSION['List']);
                $_SESSION['List'][$index+1] = $name;
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['List'][0] = $name;
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
   <body>
   <form method = "post">
   <table>

   <tr>
   <td>
   <p>Name</p>
   </td>
   <td><input type="text" name="Name" /></td>
   </tr>

   <tr>
    <td><p>State</p>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name = "State">
        <option value = "PA"> Pennsylvania</option>
        <option value = "CA"> California</option>
        <option value = "AZ"> Arizona</option>
        <option value = "NY"> New York</option>
        <option value = "FL"> Florida</option>
        <?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['List']))
        {
            foreach($_SESSION['List'] as $name)
            {
            echo '<option value="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</option>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </select>
    </td>
    </tr>

    <td><input type="submit" name = "formSubmit" value="Submit" /></td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
```

Comment: I see.  That wasn't quite what I was going for but I appreciate your help.  I'll have to look into the JQuery for what I need then